# Removing extra space at the bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

There is an extra space at the bottom of the document.
I tried setting all the padding and margin to 0 for html, body, and the bottom div.
But the space is still there. How can I get rid of this?

Here is the [link to the page.](http://jace.ciki.me/elance_draft/chat_design/)

Answer (score 2):

Note that after comment

```
<!-- end chat wrap -->
```

there is space, or `$nbsp;`. after deleting it in your root file everything should be OK.

Comment: But I don't have any space or line break after that comment. When I view it locally everything is fine, but when I upload it there goes that space at the bottom.

Comment: what is you file extention?

Comment: That `&nbsp;` is generated there after closing of `html` tag
`</body></html>nbsp`